# How does one access the methods of an embedded ActiveX control using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, object, methods, activex

I have embedded in my page an ActiveX control which communicates with a printer and an LED display.  Is there a way to access, using jQuery, the methods available within the AX control?  For example:

```
 $("#plugin").updateDisplay("COM6:", "test");
 $("#plugin").printReceipt("COM5:", "\x0a\x0a\x1dV\x42\x00");
 $("#plugin").openDrawer();
```

I know the above doesn't work, but is there some similar way of doing the equivalent using jQuery?

Also, the embedded code looks as such:

```
<object id="plugin" type="application/x-ticket" width="1" height="1">
<param name="onload" value="pluginLoaded" /></object>
```

I can access the methods using JavaScript outside of jQuery, but I thought perhaps there was a way to access the methods using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What benefit do you get out of using jquery? It's perfectly fine to use straight JS with jQuery. `document.getElementById('plugin').updateDisplay('blah', 'bleh')`. But if you really want to, you can create a plugin.

```
jquery.fn.updateDisplay = function(a, b) {
  this.each(function(index, el){
    el.updateDisplay(a, b);
  });
  return this;
}

//... and so on
```

Here's a generic way of doing it:

```
function convertMethodsTojQuery(/* methodName1, methodName2, ...*/) {

  // In some browsers (*cough* IE *cough*), the methods of DOM 
  // objects are not real JavaScript Functions and don't
  // support the apply method. Borrow Function's apply.
  var apply = Function.prototype.apply;

  for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var methodName = arguments[i];
    jQuery.fn[methodName] = (function(name) {
      return function() {
        // Save arguments so it's available in the inner looping closure
        var args = arguments;
        this.each(function(index, el){
          apply.call(el[name], el, args); 
        });
      }        
    })(name);
  }
}

// Call it like
convertMethodsTojQuery("updateDisplay", "printReceipt", "openDrawer")
```

The generic method is pretty involved (borrowing Function.prototype and self calling functions to isolate the looping variable), so it's not easy to understand unless you have a good grasp of JavaScript